# Matrix Multiplication using CUDA

Tags: c, cuda

I am struck up with Matrix multiplication on CUDA. The resultant product matrix is always zero. I have read some sample codes like [matrix multiplication in cuda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860531/matrix-multiplication-in-cuda) for resolving my problem, but all in vain.

Apart from erratic result of 0, the maximum size of "Width" (code below) is not even 512. I was not able to debug where the problem lies. May be we can discuss it on StackOverflow.

I am referring "Programming Massively Parallel Processors"

```
#include<cuda.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    void MatrixMultiplication(float *, float *, float *, int);
    const int Width = 5;
    float M[Width*Width], N[Width*Width], P[Width*Width];
    for(int i = 0; i < (Width*Width) ; i++) {
        M[i] = 5;
        N[i] = 5;
        P[i] = 0;
    }
    MatrixMultiplication(M, N, P, Width);
    for(int i = 0; i < (Width*Width) ; i++) {
        printf("%d \n", P[i]);
    }
    int quit;
    scanf("%d",&quit);
    return 0;
}

//Matrix multiplication kernel - thread specification
__global__ void MatrixMulKernel(float *Md, float *Nd, float *Pd, int Width) {
    //2D Thread ID
    int tx = threadIdx.x;
    int ty = threadIdx.y;

    //Pvalue stores the Pd element that is computed by the thread
    float Pvalue = 0;

    for(int k = 0; k < Width ; ++k) {
        float Mdelement = Md[ty*Width + k];
        float Ndelement = Nd[k*Width + tx];
        Pvalue += (Mdelement*Ndelement);
    }

    Pd[ty*Width + tx] = Pvalue;
}

void MatrixMultiplication(float *M, float *N, float *P, int Width) {
    int size = Width*Width*sizeof(float);
    float *Md, *Nd, *Pd;

    //Transfer M and N to device memory
    cudaMalloc((void**)&Md, size);
    cudaMemcpy(Md,M,size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&Nd, size);
    cudaMemcpy(Nd,N,size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    //Allocate P on the device
    cudaMalloc((void**)&Pd,size);

    //Setup the execution configuration
    dim3 dimBlock(Width,Width);
    dim3 dimGrid(1,1);

    //Launch the device computation threads!
    MatrixMulKernel<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(Md,Nd,Pd,Width);

    //Transfer P from device to host
    cudaMemcpy(P,Pd,size,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    //Free device matrices
    cudaFree(Md);
    cudaFree(Nd);
    cudaFree(Pd);
}
```

Comment: To get the proper code formatting, you need to indent all code with 4 spaces.  You can do this easily by highlighting your code and pressing `Ctrl + K`.

Comment: Thanks Jeff! Was just going to do that

Comment: If you needn't stick to your own code, the CUDA C Programming Guide has a wonderful matrix-mul implementation that can handle matrices with other dimensions than powers of two and is optimized using shared memory. Highly recommend it for real world use and for learning.

Comment: @dave drops of water make a mighty ocean. To reach at a level you have to follow step by step. e.g. If I directly use the code given in Appendix A, I might never come to know what's __syncthreads() - not considering the friendly syntax ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong. Let's analyze it :

Point 1 : The quest to remove the ever monotonic "zero value"

As noted, you must replace  `printf("%d \n", P[i]);`  as  `printf("%f \n", P[i]);`

Point 2 : Why the program fails with a value of Width 512 ?

Actually it will fail for even a small value such as 23. Why ? Because 23*23 is > 512 (The maximum number of threads that a GPU can have per block as of today!)

Answer (score 4):

You were doing fine until this point:

```
for(int i = 0; i < (Width*Width) ; i++) {
    printf("%d \n", P[i]);
}
```

I changed it to %f (because it's a float) and they all print nicely :)

```
$ ./test.exe
125.000000
125.000000
125.000000
125.000000
125.000000
125.000000
125.000000
125.000000
125.000000
125.000000
125.000000
125.000000
125.000000
125.000000
125.000000
125.000000
125.000000
125.000000
125.000000
125.000000
125.000000
125.000000
125.000000
125.000000
125.000000
```

Comment: Indeed! Though I figured it out without reading your answer and was just going to post it.

Answer (score 0):

In your MatrixMulKernel function your for loop is like

```
for(int k = 0; k < Width ; ++k) 
{
    //rest of code      
}
```

Instead of `Width`, you must use `Width*Width` as your array is of size `Width*Width`.

Comment: The whole point of using CUDA parallelism is to eliminate the computational overhead. In this case, each thread is responsible for only 1 result of the product matrix. One result (element) of product matrix can be found using "Width" iterations. So Width*Width is not going to work in any case.